# Chilli leaves are dying + misformed

Tags: diseases, leaves

Some of my young chilli plants leaves are very misformed and some have dying ends. This seems to be happening at some level to all of them, any ideas what it is?

I sprayed them with pesticide at some point which could be a cause but is there any obvious fixes?

Pictures of plants: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0eYk.jpg

Comment: What pesticide did you use?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HIJGMGZ @kevinsky not sure what exactly it is, doesn't have ingredients that I can understand. Hopefully that's enough.

Comment: The active ingredient is fatty acid which is usually soap.  If you sprayed it on with a heavy application and did not wash it off after a few minutes this could burn the leaves

Comment: @kevinsky that's true but it's affecting new leaves as well. It also seems like the plant is struggling to grow, leaving me to believe it's a lack of calcium. If you agree do you have any ideas on how to increase calcium in the soil?